# Laravel eloquent - get the count of rows of the pivot table in many to many relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I need to get the count of all the rows in the pivot `user_engagement`. I have defined a many to many relationship for users and engagements. I am getting the number with a raw query at the moment, but would like to change this query in to an eloquent one if possible:

```
$numberOfEngagements = DB::table('user_engagement')->count();
```

Comment: Your are already doing it in a very efficient way. Why would you like to make it an Eloquent query?

Answer (score 0):

Create model for your many to many relationship table and try this

```
$count = App\UserEngagement::all()->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Faster and memory friendly:

```
$count = App\UserEngagement::count();
```